# Mackie ProFX12 mixer desk to stage Monitor

Tags: mixing

I use the above desk to power 2 x 1000 watt Mackie thumps as Front of House and use 2 x 10" Mackie Actives as Stage monitors.
I haven't used the monitors in a while but while setting up today  prior to a gig i have a delay between playing a note on keyboard or sending a test down the microphone.
I am not able to see any way of reducing this delay making it almost impossible to use the stage monitors. 
Any ideas as t how to get rid of the delay.
I am using the Mon Out section to feed the monitors.

Comment: Do you have any effects set up on the mon out bus?

Comment: To rule out the mixer: what happens if you connect the keyboard directly to the stage monitors?